# fetch file name, description, id and extension from assetLibrary videos

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

```
let rootUrl = 'https://example.sharepoint.com/'
$.ajax({
  url: `${rootUrl}_api/web/lists/getByTitle('videos')/items?$select=Id,Title,VideoSetDescription&$filter=ContentType eq 'Video'`,
   type: 'GET',
headers: {
  accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'
},
success: res => console.log(res.d.results),
error: err => console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
})
```

i am getting the filename as **example**., how can i get the filename with extension 
like **example.mp4**
also i need to get the Id,Title and VideoSetDescription too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the query returns the list of items which corresponds to so called *video sets* (filter by `Video` content type). Which in turn represent the containers where *one or more files are actually stored*.  Refer [Video Experience in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.office.com/2013/03/08/enhanced-video-experience-in-sharepoint-2013/) on how videos organized in Assets library for a more details.

Having said that you could append `&$expand=Folder/Files` expression to your query which tells to return uploaded files along with the items.Then file name could be printed like this:

```
success: response => {
   response.d.results.forEach( item => {
      console.log(item.Folder.Files.results[0].Name); //print first uploaded file
   });
},
```

To retrieve only the list of items *associated with uploaded files* the following query could be utilized:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<Assets Library>')/items?$select=FileLeafRef&$filter=ContentType eq 'Video Rendition'
```